# Bash shell issue strange behavior at user input

Tags: bash, scripting

I'm hoping that another pair of eyes can see the mistake that I'm making here. It's supposed to pull data and create an html page to display the related user input (but it does nothing after the currency is entered):

```
   echo "Enter the abbreviation of the currency you want to view :" 
    read -N 3 cur

    while [ 1 ]
        do
           for cur in $@
            do 
                echo "Fetching $cur info"
                curl -ls http://bitapiherokuapp.com/bitcoin-price/$cur | grep price | awk -F "|" "{ print $2 }"  >> $cur.html
            done    
        done

        do 
            sleep 9
```

Comment: What do you expect to do with your `for` loop?  And that last `do sleep; done` is a syntax error. What did you mean with this code?

Comment: The while loop was supposed to execute the cur when the user input the currency, then pull the correct field from the url until the condition was no longer true. Was this a wrong-headed approach? Also, thank you for pointing out the syntax error. This is my first real linux script, so I really appreciate the help.

Comment: You may find https://shellcheck.net helpful for code syntax.

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think `$@` will hold anything after you use `read` to read into `cur`? Since you read into it again in the loop, the result depends on what arguments you run this script with, as that's what `$@` stands for.

Comment: oh, I didn't realize that, I've been bashing away (so to speak) on this for a couple of days straight and that escaped me. Thank you,I think that's where I went off course.